# How to find the type of an object in Go?

Tags: go, go-reflect

How do I find the type of an object in Go? In Python, I just use `typeof` to fetch the type of object. Similarly in Go, is there a way to implement the same ?

Here is the container from which I am iterating:

```
for e := dlist.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
    lines := e.Value
    fmt.Printf(reflect.TypeOf(lines))
}
```

I am not able to get the type of the object lines in this case which is an array of strings.

Comment: The standard reference aint working in my program. I should have included the source code my bad.

Comment: `fmt.Printf("%T\n", var)`

Answer (score 688, accepted):

The Go reflection package has methods for inspecting the type of variables.

The following snippet will print out the reflection type of a string, integer and float.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    tst := "string"
    tst2 := 10
    tst3 := 1.2

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(tst))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(tst2))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(tst3))

}
```

Output:

```
string
int
float64
```

see: http://play.golang.org/p/XQMcUVsOja to view it in action.

More documentation here: http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type

Comment: reflect aint working for me. I have updated the question. I have included code snippet in this case.

Answer (score 600):

I found 3 ways to return a variable's type at runtime:

**Using [string formatting](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)**

```
func typeof(v interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%T", v)
}
```

**Using [reflect package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)**

```
func typeof(v interface{}) string {
    return reflect.TypeOf(v).String()
}
```

**Using [type switch](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_switches)**

```
func typeof(v interface{}) string {
    switch v.(type) {
    case int:
        return "int"
    case float64:
        return "float64"
    //... etc
    default:
        return "unknown"
    }
}
```

Every method has a different best use case:

- string formatting - short and low footprint (not necessary to import reflect package)
- reflect package - when need more details about the type we have access to the full reflection capabilities
- type switch - allows grouping types, for example recognize all int32, int64, uint32, uint64 types as "int"

Comment: It seems that you can get rid of variable `t`, so `t := v.(type)` becomes `v.(type)`, and `_ = t` is no longer needed.

Comment: Based on a barebones benchmark, the reflect approach is surprisingly more efficient https://gist.github.com/mrap/7f08c9549289b6aea2923c27888e7e3e

Comment: `case 'T':  p.fmt.fmtS(reflect.TypeOf(arg).String())`.
fmt package using reflect to print type

Comment: Note that `v.(type)` only works in `switch` statements.

Comment: @MikeRapadas you were missing the `switch` reflection operation (e.g. `v.(type)`). I modified your benchmarks to use that in addition, and it turns out that using `switch` is far faster. Albeit that method comes with caveats - the types one is interested in must be explicitly defined to be useful.  [benchmark results](https://gist.github.com/rrrix/8939a049a069615b83c9bf0fac5ca402).

Answer (score 61):

Use the [reflect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package:

> Package reflect implements run-time reflection, allowing a program to
>   manipulate objects with arbitrary types. The typical use is to take a
>   value with static type interface{} and extract its dynamic type
>   information by calling TypeOf, which returns a Type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    b := true
    s := ""
    n := 1
    f := 1.0
    a := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(s))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(n))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(f))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a))
}
```

Produces:

```
bool
string
int
float64
[]string
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/_KymowlCWY)

Example using `ValueOf(i interface{}).Kind()`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    b := true
    s := ""
    n := 1
    f := 1.0
    a := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}

    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(b).Kind())
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(s).Kind())
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(n).Kind())
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(f).Kind())
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(a).Index(0).Kind()) // For slices and strings
}
```

Produces:

```
bool
string
int
float64
string
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/NdALPCv0RF)

Comment: reflect only displays the standard types. I am not able to get types of elements of a list container.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a slice of strings. Reflect works for any type. Please read the docs: http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/ & http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection should be enough, although there are many SO questions related to reflection in Go that should help you out as well.

Comment: ughhh, how can I determine if the type is a string? `if reflect.TypeOf(err) ==  string`?

Answer (score 47):

To get a string representation:

From http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

> %T    a Go-syntax representation of the type of the value

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
    types := []interface{} {"a",6,6.0,true}
    for _,v := range types{
        fmt.Printf("%T\n",v)
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
string
int
float64
bool
```

Answer (score 17):

I would stay away from the reflect.     package. Instead use %T

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    b := true
    s := ""
    n := 1
    f := 1.0
    a := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", b)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", s)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", n)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", f)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", a)
 }
```

Answer (score 16):

Best way is using reflection concept in Google.
`reflect.TypeOf` gives type along with the package name
`reflect.TypeOf().Kind()` gives underlining type

Answer (score 11):

To be short, please use `fmt.Printf("%T", var1)`  or its other variants in the fmt package.

Answer (score 6):

To get the type of fields in struct

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
)

type testObject struct {
  Name   string
  Age    int
  Height float64
}

func main() {
   tstObj := testObject{Name: "yog prakash", Age: 24, Height: 5.6}
   val := reflect.ValueOf(&tstObj).Elem()
   typeOfTstObj := val.Type()
   for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
       fieldType := val.Field(i)
       fmt.Printf("object field %d key=%s value=%v type=%s \n",
          i, typeOfTstObj.Field(i).Name, fieldType.Interface(),
          fieldType.Type())
   }
}
```

Output

```
object field 0 key=Name value=yog prakash type=string 
object field 1 key=Age value=24 type=int 
object field 2 key=Height value=5.6 type=float64
```

See in IDE https://play.golang.org/p/bwIpYnBQiE

Answer (score 6):

If we have this variables:

```
var counter int = 5
var message string  = "Hello"
var factor float32 = 4.2
var enabled bool = false
```

> 1: **fmt.Printf %T** format : to use this feature you should **import "fmt"**

```
fmt.Printf("%T \n",factor )   // factor type: float32
```

> 2: **reflect.TypeOf** function : to use this feature you should **import "reflect"**

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(enabled)) // enabled type:  bool
```

> 3: **reflect.ValueOf(X).Kind()** : to use this feature you should **import "reflect"**

```
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(counter).Kind()) // counter type:  int
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check the type of any variable/instance at runtime either using the "reflect" packages `TypeOf` function or by using `fmt.Printf()`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "reflect"
)

func main() {
    value1 := "Have a Good Day"
    value2 := 50
    value3 := 50.78

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(value1 ))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(value2))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(value3))
    fmt.Printf("%T",value1)
    fmt.Printf("%T",value2)
    fmt.Printf("%T",value3)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For arrays and slices use `Type.Elem()`:

```
a := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a).Elem())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `interface{}..(type)` as in this [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VypPpu6Bs9S)

```golang
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
    types := []interface{} {"a",6,6.0,true}
    for _,v := range types{
        fmt.Printf("%T\n",v)
        switch v.(type) {
        case int:
           fmt.Printf("Twice %v is %v\n", v, v.(int) * 2)
        case string:
           fmt.Printf("%q is %v bytes long\n", v, len(v.(string)))
       default:
          fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T!\n", v)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also do this trick: `switch v := v.(type)` and then do this: `case int: fmt.Printf("Twice %v is %v\n", v, v * 2)` and `case string: fmt.Printf("%q is %v bytes long\n", v, len(v))`. The inner `v` variable in switch statement shadows original `v`, so inside case code block `v` assumend as variable of type that specified in case statement.

Answer (score 2):

I have organized the following.

1. [fmt %T](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1930977/src/fmt/doc.go#L19) : a Go-syntax representation of the type of the value
2. reflect.TypeOf.[String()](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/19309779ac5e2f5a2fd3cbb34421dafb2855ac21/src/reflect/type.go#L95-L100)
3. reflect.TypeOf.[Kind()](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/19309779ac5e2f5a2fd3cbb34421dafb2855ac21/src/reflect/type.go#L102-L103)
4. [type assertions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions)

#### Example

```golang
package _test

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

func TestType(t *testing.T) {
    type Person struct {
        name string
    }
    var i interface{}
    i = &Person{"Carson"}

    for idx, d := range []struct {
        actual   interface{}
        expected interface{}
    }{
        {fmt.Sprintf("%T", "Hello") == "string", true},
        {reflect.TypeOf("string").String() == "string", true},
        {reflect.TypeOf("string").Kind() == reflect.String, true},
        {reflect.TypeOf(10).String() == "int", true},
        {reflect.TypeOf(10).Kind() == reflect.Int, true},
        {fmt.Sprintf("%T", 1.2) == "float64", true},
        {reflect.TypeOf(1.2).String() == "float64", true},
        {reflect.TypeOf(1.2).Kind() == reflect.Float64, true},
        {reflect.TypeOf([]byte{3}).String() == "[]uint8", true},
        {reflect.TypeOf([]byte{3}).Kind() == reflect.Slice, true},
        {reflect.TypeOf([]int8{3}).String() == "[]int8", true},
        {reflect.TypeOf([]int8{3}).Kind() == reflect.Slice, true},
        {reflect.TypeOf(Person{"carson"}).Kind() == reflect.Struct, true},
        {reflect.TypeOf(&Person{"carson"}).Kind() == reflect.Ptr, true},
        {fmt.Sprintf("%v", i.(*Person)) == "&{Carson}", true},
        {fmt.Sprintf("%+v", i.(*Person)) == "&{name:Carson}", true},
    } {
        if d.actual != d.expected {
            t.Fatalf("%d | %s", idx, d.actual)
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nUTPWrWufpu)</kbd>

Comment: +1 Most of the time, the point of finding out if a variable is a string is because we'd want to do something conditionally based on that. If I only care about the string case then a switch statement is overkill. This is the only answer at the moment that shows multiple simple ways of performing the type check with a comparison operator instead of banally printing the type (for beginners, it's not obvious what you'd use as the comparator).

Answer (score 2):

In case if you want to detect the type within `if` expression:

```go
if str, ok := myvar.(string); ok {
    print("It's a string")
}
```

Or without type assertion (may produce errors):

```go
if reflect.TypeOf(myvar).String() == "string" {
    print("It's a string")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `reflect.TypeOf`.

- basic type(e.g.: `int`, `string`): it will return its name (e.g.: `int`, `string`)
- struct: it will return something in the format `<package name>.<struct name>` (e.g.: `main.test`)

Answer (score -2):

[reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package comes to rescue:

```
reflect.TypeOf(obj).String()
```

Check this [demo](https://play.golang.org/p/1XJV81xjUb5)