# Name of a struct to a string

Tags: go

How do I print the name of the type of a struct, i.e. so I can include it in a print statement, i.e. something like

```
type MyStruct struct { ... }

func main() {
    fmt.Println(MyStruct.className())
}
```

If this is possible, would it be considered a slow operation? (i.e. reflection)

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/20170275/6309

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct{}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", MyStruct{})
}
```

Output:

```
main.MyStruct
```

The [`fmt`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) `%T` print verb gives a Go-syntax representation of the type of the value.

The Go `fmt` package uses the `reflect` package for run-time reflection.