# using reflection in Go to get the name of a struct

Tags: go, struct, reflection, types

I found this question with this great answers:

[How to find a type of a object in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170275/how-to-find-a-type-of-a-object-in-golang)

I played around with the answer and tried to get the name of a struct in the same way:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "reflect"
)

type Ab struct {

}

func getType(myvar interface{}) string {
        return reflect.TypeOf(myvar).Name()
}

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

        tst := "string"
        tst2 := 10
        tst3 := 1.2
        tst4 := new(Ab)

        fmt.Println(getType(tst))
        fmt.Println(getType(tst2))
        fmt.Println(getType(tst3))
        fmt.Println(getType(tst4))

}
```

Go playground: http://play.golang.org/p/tD8mygvETH

But the output is:

```
Hello, playground
string
int
float64


Program exited.
```

Expected output would be:

```
Hello, playground
string
int
float64
Ab

Program exited.
```

I tried to figure out by reading the documentation but didn't find the issue about that. So, sorry for the very general question, but:

What's the reason, `reflect.TypeOf().Name()` does not work with (this) struct(s)?

Comment: seems if you do Ab{}, instead of new(Ab) you get expected result

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In your example you pass a value of pointer type (`*Ab`), not a struct type.

#### Sticking to `Type.Name()`

If it is not a pointer, `Type.Name()` will properly return `Ab`. In case of pointer if you still want the struct's name, you can use `Type.Elem()` to get the element's type:

```
func getType(myvar interface{}) string {
    if t := reflect.TypeOf(myvar); t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        return "*" + t.Elem().Name()
    } else {
        return t.Name()
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
tst4 := Ab{}
tst5 := new(Ab)
fmt.Println(getType(tst4))
fmt.Println(getType(tst5))
```

Output (try your modified example on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ZiiLpxq1bY)):

```
Ab
*Ab
```

**Note:**

Note that as `Type.Name()` does not resolve pointers, it would not work if the value passed is a pointer to pointer, e.g. `**Ab`, while as `Type.String()` automatically resolves pointers, would work in this case too.

We can easily make our `getType()` function to work with `**Ab` too (or with any depth of pointers):

```
func getType(myvar interface{}) (res string) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(myvar)
    for t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
        res += "*"
    }
    return res + t.Name()
}
```

Calling it with values:

```
tst4 := Ab{}
tst5 := new(Ab)
tst6 := &tst5 // type of **Ab
tst7 := &tst6 // type of ***Ab
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ppETDiN_v0)):

```
Ab
*Ab
**Ab
***Ab
```

#### Using `Type.String()`

A simpler and better approach would be to use `Type.String()` instead of `Type.Name()` which automatically handles pointers and also includes package name. E.g.:

```
func getType(myvar interface{}) string {
    return reflect.TypeOf(myvar).String()
}
```

For the modified example it outputs:

```
string
int
float64
main.Ab
*main.Ab
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/VDySY-tdW9).

Comment: Second alternative also works for e.g. `**Ab`, first one doesn't.

Comment: @DanieleD Added to the answer, and showed how it still can be used to support `**Ab` (or any depth of pointers).

Answer (score 23):

fmt has a cool `%T` tag as well

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Potato struct {
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("I have a %T, an %T and a %T\n", Potato{}, http.StatusMultipleChoices, &http.Response{})
}
```

outputs `I have a main.Potato, an int and a *http.Response`
https://play.golang.org/p/6z7_0BSitm

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `new` returns pointer, following should get the desired result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Ab struct {
}

func getType(myvar interface{}) {
    valueOf := reflect.ValueOf(myvar)

    if valueOf.Type().Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        fmt.Println(reflect.Indirect(valueOf).Type().Name())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(valueOf.Type().Name())
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    tst := "string"
    tst2 := 10
    tst3 := 1.2
    tst4 := new(Ab)

    getType(tst)
    getType(tst2)
    getType(tst3)
    getType(tst4)

}
```

Output is

```
Hello, playground
string
int
float64
Ab
```