# type reflection of pointer to struct in go

Tags: go, pointers, reflection

I'm having problems determine the type of a struct when I only have a pointer to the struct.

```
type TypeA struct {
  Foo string
}

type TypeB struct {
  Bar string
}
```

I have to implement the following callback:

```
func Callback(param interface{}) {

}
```

`param` can be `*TypeA` or `*TypeB`.

How can I determine the Type of `param`?

`reflect.TypeOf(param)` seems not to work with a pointer.

When I do this

```
func Callback(param interface{}) {
  n := reflect.TypeOf(param).Name()
  fmt.Printf(n)
}
```

The output is empty

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer types such as `*TypeA` are *unnamed* types, hence querying their names will give you the empty string. Use `Type.Elem()` to get to the element type, and print its name:

```
func Callback(param interface{}) {
    n := reflect.TypeOf(param).Elem().Name()
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

Testing it:

```
Callback(&TypeA{})
Callback(&TypeB{})
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/W6m-IHitBI6)):

```
TypeA
TypeB
```

Another option is to use the `Type.String()` method:

```
func Callback(param interface{}) {
    n := reflect.TypeOf(param)
    fmt.Println(n.String())
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dnMTQsrpGE2)):

```
*main.TypeA
*main.TypeB
```

See related questions:

[using reflection in Go to get the name of a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790935/using-reflection-in-go-to-get-the-name-of-a-struct/35791105#35791105)

[Identify non builtin-types using reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310538/identify-non-builtin-types-using-reflect/37292523#37292523)