# JSON decoded value is treated as float64 instead of int

Tags: go

I have a json response from a api as `map[message:Login Success. userid:1]`

Server:

```
c.JSON(200, gin.H{"message": "Login Success.", "userid": 1})
```

Client:

```
var result map[string]interface{}
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result)

msg, ok := result["message"].(string)
if !ok {
    msg = "Something went wrong."
}
userID, ok := result["userid"].(int)
if !ok {
    userID = 0
}
```

But `userID, ok := result["userid"].(int)` always fails. I've even tried using:

```
switch v := x.(type) {
case nil:
    fmt.Println("x is nil")          
case int: 
    fmt.Println("x is", v)           
case bool, string:
    fmt.Println("x is bool or string")
default:
    fmt.Println("type unknown")      
}
```

And it just gave me **unknown**. Why is the integer not being taken as integer?

---

It looks like its treating the value as `float64`.

Comment: Maybe it is a uint, or int8, or another int type

Comment: @SeanF I doubt that's the case. I just tried `c.JSON(200, gin.H{"message": "Login Success.", "userid": int(1)})` and its still failing.

Comment: Why would that change anything?

Comment: Why don't you just get the type and tell me what the type is because it is not int, that is for sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170275/how-to-find-a-type-of-an-object-in-go

Comment: Ok I just saw it. Its `float64` but why is it treating it as float?

Comment: Call the programmer on the phone and ask him why he chose float64 instead of int

Comment: Most likely he sends all numbers across as float64 because it was easy to do it that way

Comment: You mean the `gin.H` ints are getting packed as floats?

Comment: Maybe, who knows what gin.H does. It is the most likely scenario. Far more likely than your assertion that golang type assertion does not work with int. Also more likely than the possibility that the json encode or decode converts int to float.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just uses the `json.Marshall` function to encode whatever is in `gin.H` and `gin.H` is just a `map[string]interface{}` there has got to be another reason.

Comment: You make far too many assumptions. Nik just proved this latest one wrong.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here you can find the explanation why you are getting `float64` and not `int`:

Check doc for [Decode](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode)

> See the documentation for Unmarshal for details about the conversion of JSON into a Go value.

And there [see](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:

```
float64, for JSON numbers
```

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. I don’t think this behaviour is a good idea, though.